# Why angular material select is overflowing the screen

Tags: css, angular, typescript, material-design, angular-material

I am using angular material select in my application which you can find here https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview. The problem is when we place the select near the bottom of the screen it, and when it is opened, It overflow the screen. This is the screenshot of what I am experiencing. What kind of css is needed to prevant this from happening.

```
   <mat-select style="margin-bottom: 0px;" placeholder="{{input1.title}}" >
                            <mat-option>None</mat-option>
                                               <mat-option *ngFor="let opt_value of input1.enumNameGroups[grp_value] let i = index" value="{{input1.enumidGroups[grp_value][i]}}" >{{opt_value}}</mat-option>
                                                </mat-optgroup>

      </mat-select>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the desired behaviour? Where would you want the select to go if there's not enough space at the bottom?

Comment: The Material Select component handles this itself, check the documentation link you included and resize your screen to see it in action. This means something is wrong in your layout or you're getting errors.

Comment: @bugs : Yes, I want select to go up if there is not enough space.

Comment: @Jaydeep Show the code of select.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 : This is generated by material design pagination Using this snippt.     <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [length]="tableData.totalrecord"  
                 [pageSize]="20"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20,100,500,1000,2000]"
                 [showFirstLastButtons]="true"
                 (page)="on_page_change()">
  </mat-paginator>

Comment: But overall I am using basic material select code to generate anykind of select input like one I edited in the question.

Comment: hello is there any way to overcome this situation?

Comment: I have checked the behavior of example given in the link. It was coming perfectly as desired....What I have seem to miss?

Comment: @carsten I described my layout here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996048/how-to-make-this-angular-flex-layout-full-height-based-on-screen-size/49996559#49996559 but still I am not able to get any hint on how to get desired behaviour.

Comment: @bugs Is there any thing that I can do? this is just not happening for this select but all select this is happening in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default css of the paginator panel to place it anywhere on the screen:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Change the properties of the class depending on where you want to place the element.